# Oracle SQL - Group by a column and extract other values to columns

Tags: sql, oracle

My idea is to do something like this:

INPUT:

```
ID  CURRENCY    AMOUNT
1   RUS         14,55
1   USD         22,22
1   PLN         444,44
2   PLN         22
```

Then I want to group by ID and get output:

```
ID  CUR_1   AMOUNT_1    CUR_2   AMOUNT_2    CUR_3   AMOUNT_3
1   RUS     14,55       USD     22,22       PLN     444,44
2   PLN     22
```

It is important to combine the right amount with right currency. Maximal number of pairs is 3 like for an ID=1. It may vary from 1 to 3.

I tried using `LISTAGG` but it will generate problem with further processing of the data.

Comment: Search for `PIVOT`

Comment: Or do it in the front end where this kind of thing really belongs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * 
  from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by null) rn
          from t)
  pivot (max(currency) cur, sum(amount) amt for rn in (1, 2, 3))
```

Test:

```
with t(id, currency, amount) as (
    select 1, 'RUS',  14.55 from dual union all
    select 1, 'USD',  22.22 from dual union all
    select 1, 'PLN', 444.44 from dual union all
    select 2, 'PLN',  22    from dual )
select * 
  from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by null) rn
          from t)
  pivot (max(currency) cur, sum(amount) amt for rn in (1, 2, 3))
```

Output:

```
        ID 1_CUR      1_AMT 2_CUR      2_AMT 3_CUR      3_AMT
---------- ----- ---------- ----- ---------- ----- ----------
         1 RUS        14,55 USD        22,22 PLN       444,44
         2 PLN           22
```

Comment: Ok, this works but what if I gave two rows that are of the same currency:

`1   RUS         14,55
1   RUS         22,22
...`

Then I want to have result:

`1   RUS     36,77 ...`
And this approach doesn't sum. It extracts it into seperate column.

Comment: So group data at first by `id` and `currency` and then apply `row_number` and `pivot` or use `dense_rank` instead of `row_number`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with `dense_rank`. I changed one line to `select tab.*, dense_rank() over (partition by id order by currency) rn from`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a virtual table for each row using a subquery, then join the virtual tables by ID into a single row.